Trying to test a transaction on a custom Testnet
We have a custom Testnet that we'd like to test Safe transactions on. We have deployed the necessary contracts:

Singleton contract
Factory contract
Safe contract

We'd like to now test the safe transactions on our WebApp using the @safe-global/safe-apps-sdk, but it doesn't fulfill invoked promises.
How do we do set this up better? Do we need to use the api-kit?
What are the steps that we need to take?
Best,
Memo

You can follow this guide to set up and run Safe infrastructure locally, and then run it in production.
Hope this helps! Best, Louis

Thanks Louis. So if I understand correctly, I need to deploy these contracts on my Testnet, and then run Safe Infrastructure locally to host the signing?

Yes you will have to basically run a fork of Safe Wallet UI with support for your own network; then you can use the UI (including safe apps) on your test network. What transactions exactly will you be testing out?

I'd like to have the Safe Wallet make transactions directly on our contract, as a lot of our users have the Safe Wallet!
So, here's the thing: I set up the local safe infrastructure and I deployed the proxy contract onto our chain, and also added the SafeProxyFactory information on the txs/admin page of the local infrastructure.
Calling  Get on /v1/contracts/0xb519B82b3F06545f49a12E9D13A8246c21acEcE0 endpoint yields 0 results. Even /v1/contracts yields zero results, though the txs/admin detects our contract by updating the latest tx block.
Is this normal?

Following the guide steps, you should also add the mastercopies addresses on the txs/admin SafeMastercopies section. Is 0xb519B82b3F06545f49a12E9D13A8246c21acEcE0 a Safe? In this case you should probably use the endpoint /v1/safe/<safe_address> instead. You can make sure your Safe was indexed by taking a look at txs/admin SafeContracts section. Could you confirm it works? Thanks in advance  Best, Louis
